# split scala code into modules with one module for imports only

Tags: scala, import, module

I have a main scala module with my main object with multiple function. I import many fundamental and necessary packages in order to run the code.

I have splitted the code into few modules and each module has got an object with some functions taken from original main module.

I do not know what to do about imports. I thought I can just create a separate module for imports and this is what I have tried but obviously it does not work.

is there a way to skip having imports in each module separately and just to have one module for all necessary imports?

Comment: By "module" do you mean "file" or something else?

Comment: module = file (in the same dir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages allow re-exporting imports, but Scala isn't one of them. You can do something like this:

```
object Imports {
  type Type1 = some.package.Type1
  // only if Type1 is a Scala type with a companion object
  val Type1 = some.package.Type1
  ...
  // you can also define methods here
}

// elsewhere
import Imports._
```

In most circumstances this is a bad idea. It also doesn't help with static members of Java types.

Comment: so if you have a script with many functions in it theb how would you clean it? i see the way to split into many modules is not the way due to imports problem.

Comment: 1. Basically any IDE makes it a non-problem. 2. Even if you don't use an IDE, you can import everything from a package (`import some.package._`), decreasing number of imports a lot.